# Optimize property get in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have an application that calls to the get function of an object in an annimation loop. Precisely 
I have something like

> var value = this.get('controller.data')['somekey'];

where `controller.data` is a hash.

The problem is that when I run the profiling, the call to get function occupy 50% of the computation I have in my animation loop.

How can I optimize this call ?

Comment: Is it possible to circumvent Ember in that call completely and store that data elsewhere? Is it data-bound?

Comment: what do you mean by data-bound ?

Comment: isn't it just `this.get('controller.data.somekey')`